# how to remove the item from an object in angular

Tags: angular

I have an object like this:

```
  {
    first_name: "acasc"
    last_name: "acsac"
    email: "acac"
    mobile_number: "acac"
    password: "acac"
    confirm_password: "acac"

   }
```

here is my requirement:

if the password and confirm password matches I have to delete the confirm_password. how can I do that.

Comment: `delete obj.confirm_password`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `delete object.key`.

Check the MDN documentation [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

In your case,

```js
var data =  {
        first_name: "acasc",
        last_name: "acsac",
        email: "acac",
        mobile_number: "acac",
        password: "acac",
        confirm_password: "acac"
       };
       
      console.log('without delete', data);
      if(data.password === data.confirm_password) delete data.confirm_password;
      console.log('after delete', data);
```

You can use

```
delete data.confirm_password
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way

```
let obj =  {
          first_name: "acasc",
          last_name: "acsac",
          email: "acac",
          mobile_number: "acac",
          password: "acac",
          confirm_password: "acac"
         }
         if(obj.password === obj.confirm_password){
           delete obj.confirm_password;
         }
         console.log(obj);
```